# How can I set up my htaccess to do this?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up my htaccess file to perform these redirections:

**http://www.mysite.com/about** should link to **http://www.mysite.com/content/pages/about.php**

**http://www.mysite.com/login** should link to **http://www.mysite.com/content/pages/login.php**

**http://www.mysite.com/prices** should link to **http://www.mysite.com/content/pages/prices.php**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To only redirect URLs you have provided you can use this kind of rule (you can add other pages to the list of you need):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(about|login|prices)$ /content/pages/$1.php [L]
```

To redirect **ALL non-existing pages** to `/content/pages/PAGE_NAME.php`, you can use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do not do anything for already existing files (like images/css/js etc)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# redirect everything else
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content/pages/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /content/pages/$1.php [L]
```

**NOTES:**
You need to place these rules into .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.